# Unable to Install published .NET C# program

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, publish

I'm currently struggling with a problem I'm having after publishing an application that’s written using C# in Visual Studio 2010. The application runs without errors or warnings in debugging mode. In my application I’m using 6 different 3rd party .DLL:s, http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/ and vcinet2.dll.

The application is installable on my own computer and runs here without errors, however when I try installing it on a different computer it doesn’t work. And this is what happens: 
The application is (after publishing through the publish tool I VS 2010) accessible in the folder specified. I run the setup.exe file and it starts installing. It finishes installing but directly after this (after a shortcut has been created on the desktop and the application starts to load) the application crashes. It says “MyProgram has stopped working, check online? Close the program? Debug the program?” When I click on more details this is shown:

```
“Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MyProgram.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4f9150a6
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17651
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4e2111c0
  Exception Code:   e0434352
  Exception Offset: 0000d36f
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1053
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt “
```

What I have found after browsing the Internet for this is that people get this problem when they are using a remote server for the publishing, or updates from a webpage. But I don’t, I’m simply using the “From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM” in the “How will users install the application” window in VS 2010.

I have been working with this for a couple of days now, mostly checking compatibility with the .DLL:s etc. But I haven’t found a solution for this.

Both computers are using x86 platform and my “platform target” in VS2010 is “x86”.

When I looked closer to “e0434352” (error code) I found that this was some sort of error for every Exception I VS2010, is this correct or have I misinterpreted this?

I would really appreciate any help I can get, I have a feeling that it is a simple solution with some setting in VS2010 that’s wrong but I can’t figure it out!

I’m not getting any exceptions in the beginning of the start of the program, which leads me to think that it is a setting which is wrong?

Best regards 
Erik

Comment: Do you have VMware Workstation by any way? Because then you could debug with your local Visual Studio inside a VM with a clean System where the error happens...

Comment: accfews: Do you mean the option under Security "This is a full trust application"? In that case this is already set. 
chrfin: No, is it a good idea to download (get) this? Any good tutorital or similar you know?

Comment: You didn't implement an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.  So you get no help diagnosing the unhandled exception that crashes your program beyond what little Windows knows about failing managed code.  Use e.UnhandledException.ToString() in such an event handler and log or display the value.  Good enough in 95% of all cases to diagnose the reason why it bombed.

Comment: Where should I put the handler?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the application files in the project -> publish properties?  I have seen it where VS didn't automatically add the libraries I wanted in the application files.  This should make sure that they get installed.

Comment: My application Files are as follows: The 5 .DLL:s from Pcap (Include (Auto)) and the vcinet2.dll (Include) (this was previously (Prerequists(Auto)) but I changed it to Include though it said that it missed this on the other computer. along with these files are my: MyProgram.exe, MyProgram.exe.config, MyProgram.exe.manifest. Also in my Applications Folder in "publish" after publishing I have the different .deploys, but the .manifest isn't a .deploy? Should it be like this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error happens when I use libraries of a Framework less than the framework that I use to compile the project.

There are some object that you use in your window form that from a Library of netframework 2 for example Microsoft.VisualBasics.PowerPacks.Vs that don't has a similar in Framework 4.

How to solve the problem?

Go to the project
expand the reference
Inspect the property of framework, usually the penultimate of the list is this version less than the framework use to compile change in the same property list the 'local copy´to true
Recompile and the application works